# Non-invocable member 'HMACSHA512' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 private void creatPassordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHach, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using ( var hmac = System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512()){
                passwordSalt = hmac.key;
                passwordHach = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
```

i got this messege 
Non-invocable member 'HMACSHA512' cannot be used like a method

Comment: Use `new` keyword, because you're calling a constructor: `var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512()`.

Comment: Nobody never reads exception messages:( _"Non-invocable member 'HMACSHA512' cannot be used like a method"_ means that `System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512` (spoiler: it's a class) is non-invocable member and you cannot use it like a method.

Comment: thanks Tetsuya Yamamoto it's work fine now. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting that error because you're not using the `new` keyword. Your code should look something like the following:

```
private void creatPassordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHach, out byte[] passwordSalt)
{
    using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
    {
        passwordSalt = hmac.key;
        passwordHach = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks dear it works fine